# Liquibase diff both comparing hibernate models doesn't find any differences while the different set of packages is passed to it:

Tags: java, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

In the `build.gradle` I have saet up the liquibase config to run the `diff` task of the liquibase gradle plugin.

```
liquibase {
    activities {
        main {
            changeLogFile "$buildDir/generated-migrations.xml"            
            url 'hibernate:spring:rf.dom.billing.model.contractor,rf.dom.billing.model.billing,rf.dom.billing.model.dict,rf.dom.billing.model.meta,rf.dom.billing.model.service?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect&hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy'
            referenceUrl 'hibernate:spring:rf.dom.billing.model.contractor,rf.dom.billing.model.billing,rf.dom.billing.model.dict,rf.dom.billing.model.meta?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect&hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy'
            logLevel 'debug' 
        }
        runList = "main"
    }
}
```

i.e url just have for one more package than reference (`rf.dom.billing.model.service`)

I expect the tables from the entities of that class to be shown as a diff, but the outpu shows

```
02:48:03.323 INFO  [liquibase.diff.output.changelog.DiffToChangeLog$1]: No changes found, nothing to do
02:48:03.324 INFO  [liquibase.integration.commandline.Main]: Liquibase command 'diffChangeLog' was executed successfully.
```

How to work it around and get the difference, based on the different number of packages under the diff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/blob/84c7fe863c8ddf67c1cd9fa86d870b13ffcbad21/src/main/java/liquibase/ext/hibernate/database/HibernateSpringPackageDatabase.java#L78) it should work. If you increase the log level you should be able to see the *Found package* messages to confirm that Liquibase is correctly loading your url .